# Creating a side tab

Tags: android, tabs

I was able to create a tab layout using the tutorial in [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).  I was wondering if I can put a side tab on it. [image: This is only a Mockup I made.]. When you click an Item on the left side, an activity will be displayed on the right side.

I was wondering If I can do it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes you can do this. Your solution will depend on how your project is constructed. Is it based on Activities? is it based on fragments? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can divide the screen in two parts using the `FrameLayout` and use the `Fragments`. On the left side load separate `Fragment` and on right side load `Fragment` according to the items selected from left side.

Comment: In the tutorial on androidhive, he created the tabs using fragments. I think I'm going to stick with fragments. Actually I'm not quite sure. Sorry.

Comment: So when using FrameLayout, I'm going to create another Fragment class for the left side?

Comment: Yes, exactly using FrameLayout you can load a Fragment class into it. And divide that both framelayout into 20% and 80% of the screen. So that it will cover that much space in the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to design your layout as below:

Here its `fragment_top_rated.xml` file code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/passenger"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:weightSum="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can load this screen on tabs click with the fragments into it.

**EDITED:**

Supposing that you have developed your project exactly same as the defined demo of you question link.

In your Tabactivity as you select places tab load the Fragment of places in the left side. 
It defined in link on tab selected you just have to load fragments.

**PlacesFragment**

In your `PlacesFragment` write code as below:

```
public class PlacesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated,
                container, false);
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment m_fragSet = new GamesFragment();
        ft1.replace(R.id.frameLayout2, m_fragSet);
        ft1.commit();

        FragmentManager fmg = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = fmg.beginTransaction();
        Fragment m_frag = new MoviesFragment();
        ftrans.replace(R.id.frameLayout1, m_frag);
        ftrans.commit();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Create right side fragment Games

```
public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is **`MoviesFragment.java`**

```
public class MoviesFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

In your **`TabsAdapter`** define as below:

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    FragmentActivity context;
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,FragmentActivity act) {
        super(fm);
        context=act;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new TopRatedFragment();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new GamesFragment();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new MoviesFragment();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }

}
```

Here is the **Output**

[image]

Comment: how can I put a different fragment class on each side? sorry still an android newbie.

Comment: So I'm going to create a new xml file? fragment places and fragment maps right?

Comment: given that i have already done the two xml files and and the two classes, how should I put the two xml files on the layout that you designed at the top of your answer? when I click the places tab, the layout you designed will be displayed

Comment: Inflate that layout's in your classes which you have created the way i have done in my answer in `MapFragment` and `PlacesFragment`. And load the fragments on Click of the Places Tab and load the right fragment from the Places Fragment onCreateView() method only.

Comment: Hi, I'm kinda struggling to do it correctly. I'm sorry but I would be really thankful if you can tell me how to do it step by step, I have done the layouts and the classes, but there are a lot of errors when I copied your code in TabsPagerAdapter class. I'm very sorry, I hope you could still help me.

Comment: @MiguelRivera Check out my updated answer. If still any query let me know.

Comment: I get an error in these lines "  Fragment m_fragSet = new TabTwo();
        ft1.replace(R.id.frameDisplay, m_fragSet);"

It is saying " Type mismatch: cannot convert from TabTwo to Fragment "

Comment: Have you defined the `TabTwo` as `Fragment` ?

Comment: Check out carefully you might be using the `support.v4.app.fragment` in your TabTwo fragment and it must be asking for the same library to include.

Comment: What is correct atleast post your code with the `imports` which you have added in your `TabTwo` class. and the class where you are writing this code `" Fragment m_fragSet = new TabTwo(); ft1.replace(R.id.frameDisplay, m_fragSet);"`

Comment: Show me the code of class where you are trying to instantiate `" Fragment m_fragSet = new TabTwo(); ft1.replace(R.id.frameDisplay, m_fragSet);"` with its imports

Comment: In your code you need write this line first ` View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_one, container, false);` and after that try to load the fragment section part in your `TabOne` class.

Comment: That was the trick! I was planning to design the layout of my TabOne with a ListView and a Divider but I think loading fragments was a better idea. Do you think so too?

Comment: Well the way you are thinking is not feasible way of implementation you can not load the two fragments in ListFragments , if you want that then you have to create one of your `GamesFragment()` or `MoviesFragment()` as `ListFragment` then only it will work. So just make the `TabOne` as `Fragment` only.

Comment: I just put List fragment because I was considering putting a listview already.